# Prepare and Perform segue throws different values

Tags: swift, segue

I want to transfer variable from first ViewController to the second one.

ViewController1:

```
class First_VC: UIViewController {
    
...
    @IBAction func touch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let indexPath = table.indexPath(for: sender.superview!.superview as! UITableViewCell) {
            let cell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            selectedName = cell?.textLabel?.text
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource =   self
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "segue" else { return }
        guard let vc2 = segue.destination as? Second_VC else { return }
        vc2.name = selectedName
    }
}
...
```

ViewController2

```
class Second_VC: UIViewController {
    ...

    var name: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(name ?? "1")

        proName.text = name
    }
}
```

When i use print in the ViewController 2 i get this: (two different prints with 1sec delaying)

"1"

"Yatoro雨" -> the variable I'm looking for (works only if performSegue is added)

In my app label.text changes according to the first print that is "1" and it doesn't see the second one. How to make xCode change proName.text according to the second print?

Comment: Are you saying the `viewDidLoad` is being called twice in `Second_VC`? Or do you have a second `print(name)` somewhere? If so, show where the second `print` is.

Comment: @HangarRash I think that my print is being called twice by 1)func prepare and then by 2)performSegue. If I delete performSegue from the xcode, then i will get just one print (the first one, that is "1")

Comment: First of all snake_case names like `First_VC` are *unswifty*. It seems that you connected the segue to the table view **cell**. Reconnect it to the view controller.

Comment: From what I guess, you did you segue from the Button (or the cell) in `First_VC` to `Second_VC`, which will perform the segue before the code is executed in the IBAction method, so it's triggered from "Storyboard", and then, the IBAction func is called, and it's triggered by code.

Answer (score 0):

Some commentators below suggested to re-connect my segue through View Controller and explained why. It was the reason